# Unable to receive serial data

Tags: c, serial-port, mingw, codeblocks

I modified serial communication loopback code written by someone else in C (codeblocks/mingw) under windows platform. I am able to send the data correctly. I verified this by opening terminal software. But I am unable to receive the data. I get the error message error reading from input buffer 998 for ReadFile() in the below code. Not sure what the mistake is.
I am using two CP210x USB to serial modules and connected TxD to RxD of one to other.

```
#include    <windows.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <commdlg.h>
//#include  <windef.h>
#include <time.h>

int nread,nwrite;

void myDelay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hSerial;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    COMMCONFIG dcbSerialParams;
    char *words, *buffRead, *buffWrite;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten, dwBytesRead;

    if(argc<3)
    {
        printf("Enter the com port as command line parameter and t for transmitter and r for receiver\n");
        printf("Example: Serial.exe com4 t\n");
        return(1);
    }
    hSerial = CreateFile(argv[1],GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    if ( hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            printf(" serial port does not exist \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" some other error occured\n");
        }

        return(1);
    }


    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb))
    {
        printf("error getting state \n");
        return(1);
    }

    dcbSerialParams.dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams.dcb);

    // Set various serial port parameters.

    dcbSerialParams.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;

    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDsrSensitivity= FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fAbortOnError = TRUE;

    if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb))
    {
        printf(" error setting serial port state \n");
        return(1);
    }


    GetCommTimeouts(hSerial,&timeouts);
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier= 10;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts))
    {
        printf("error setting port state \n");
        return(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        // Use a delay of 500 msec
        myDelay(500);
        if(!strcmp(argv[2],"t"))
        {

            printf("Write Mode\n");
            //****************Write Operation*********************//
            words = "This is a string to be written to serial port COM1";
            nwrite = strlen(words);

            buffWrite = words;
            dwBytesWritten = 0;

            if (!WriteFile(hSerial, buffWrite, nwrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL))
            {
                printf("error writing to output buffer \n");
                return(1);
            }

        }


//***************Read Operation******************//

        else
        {
            dwBytesRead = 0;
            nread = strlen(words);

            if (!ReadFile(hSerial, buffRead, nread, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
            {
                printf("error reading from input buffer %d\n", GetLastError());
                continue;
            }
            printf("Data read from read buffer is \n %s \n",buffRead);

        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Error 998 is ERROR_NOACCESS, "Invalid access to memory location".  Tells you with 100% confidence that you are passing a bad pointer to ReadFile().  You are, you never initialized *buffRead*.  A much better declaration is `BYTE buffRead[4096];`  And pass a correct value for the buffer size, that will be 4096.  The printf() statement is wrong as well, you will not get a properly zero-terminated string.

Comment: Worked. Did not notice that memory is not allocated. If you write this as an answer, I can mark this as an answer. Now it works for me. Also few changes I did in receive section to avoid garbage display. Some more changes I will be doing as part of clean up code '
 else  {
                if(dwBytesRead)
                {
                    for(count=0;count<dwBytesRead;count++)
                        printf("%c",buffRead[count]);
                }
            }'

Answer (score 0):

Read and Write to COM port is blocking each other making your reading almost alway timeout when the FIFO's runs out. Also there could be some data oin the FIFO's already so... If you sending and receiving too big chunks of data the data loss is more probable in this way.

Here small ancient example of non threaded COM port access

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- port class ver: 1.0 ------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _port_h
#define _port_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class port
        {
public: HANDLE       hnd;
        AnsiString   error;
        DWORD        rlen,wlen,err;
        DCB          rs232_state;
        COMMPROP     properties;
        COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
        COMSTAT      stat;
        port();
        ~port();
        int  open(AnsiString name);
        void close();
        int  get_stat();        // err,stat
        int  get_timeouts();    // timeouts
        int  set_timeouts();
        int  get_properties();  // properties
        int  get_rs232_state(); // rs232_state
        int  set_rs232_state();
        void rst_rs232_state();
        void out(BYTE data)  { WriteFile(hnd,&data,1,&wlen,NULL); }
        void in (BYTE *data) { ReadFile (hnd, data,1,&rlen,NULL); }
        void in (char *data) { ReadFile (hnd, data,1,&rlen,NULL); }
        void out(BYTE *data,DWORD len) { WriteFile(hnd,data,len,&wlen,NULL); }
        void in (BYTE *data,DWORD len) { ReadFile (hnd,data,len,&rlen,NULL); }
        };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
port::port()
        {
        rlen=0;
        wlen=0;
        err =0;
        error="";
        hnd=NULL;
        rst_rs232_state();
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
port::~port()
        {
        close();
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int port::open(AnsiString name)
        {
        close();
        rlen=0;
        wlen=0;
        hnd=CreateFile( name.c_str(),GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,0,NULL);
        if (hnd==NULL) return 0;
        get_timeouts();
        get_properties();
        get_rs232_state();

        timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout;
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant;
        timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
        timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant;

        properties.wPacketLength;
        properties.wPacketVersion;
        properties.dwServiceMask;
        properties.dwReserved1;
        properties.dwMaxTxQueue;
        properties.dwMaxRxQueue;
        properties.dwMaxBaud;
        properties.dwProvSubType;
        properties.dwProvCapabilities;
        properties.dwSettableParams;
        properties.dwSettableBaud;
        properties.wSettableData;
        properties.wSettableStopParity;
        properties.dwCurrentTxQueue;
        properties.dwCurrentRxQueue;
        properties.dwProvSpec1;
        properties.dwProvSpec2;
        properties.wcProvChar[1];

        return 1;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void port::close()
        {
        if (hnd==NULL) return;
        CloseHandle(hnd);
        hnd=NULL;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int port::get_stat()
        {
        if (ClearCommError(hnd,&err,&stat)) return 1;
        error=GetLastError();
        return 0;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int port::get_timeouts()
        {
        if (GetCommTimeouts(hnd,&timeouts)) return 1;
        error=GetLastError();
        get_stat();
        return 0;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int port::set_timeouts()
        {
        if (SetCommTimeouts(hnd,&timeouts)) return 1;
        error=GetLastError();
        get_stat();
        return 0;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int port::get_properties()
        {
        if (GetCommProperties(hnd,&properties)) return 1;
        error=GetLastError();
        get_stat();
        return 0;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int port::get_rs232_state()
        {
        if (GetCommState(hnd,&rs232_state)) return 1;
        error=GetLastError();
        get_stat();
        return 0;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int port::set_rs232_state()
        {
        if (SetCommState(hnd,&rs232_state)) return 1;
        error=GetLastError();
        get_stat();
        return 0;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void port::rst_rs232_state()
        {
        rs232_state.BaudRate    = CBR_9600;
        rs232_state.ByteSize    = 8;
        rs232_state.Parity      = NOPARITY;
        rs232_state.StopBits    = ONESTOPBIT;
        rs232_state.fOutxCtsFlow= FALSE;
        rs232_state.fOutxDsrFlow= FALSE;
        rs232_state.fOutX       = FALSE;
        rs232_state.fInX        = FALSE;
        rs232_state.fBinary     = FALSE;
        rs232_state.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is in **C++/VCL** so just rewrite `AnsiString` to `char*` or any string type you got and also change the File routines to yours. If you do not have access to classes rewrite to **C**.  Usage is simple:

```
// globals and init
port com;
com.open("COM2");
com.timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout        =10;
com.timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier =10;
com.timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant   =10;
com.timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
com.timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant  =10;
com.set_timeouts();

// send/recv
char q;
com.out(`x`); // send x
com.in (&q); // recv ...
```

You should use threads to remedy this because without the threads the communications is blocking. Anyway without threads for loop-back you should:

1. set both COM ports to the same protocol
2. always first send then receive
3. set small enough timeout (not to block for too long)
4. expect data loss and timeouts (and handle as such... do not block sending by it)
5. send just `BYTES` not all COM ports have big FIFOs along the way...

To be more safe do the reading inside thread ... like:

```
volatile bool _stop=false; // set this to true when you want to exit
unsigned long __stdcall thread_com(LPVOID p)
        {
        char q;
        for (;!_stop;)
         {
         com.in (&q); // recv ...
         if (q<32) q=`.`; // data loss due to timeout if not sending `0..31` of coarse
         Sleep(1); // just not to burn CPU ...
         }
        }

HANDLE thread_com_hnd=CreateThread(0,0,thread_com,NULL,0,0); // do this only after COM port is initialized
```

Comment: I was looking for very simple C code for receive/transmit and I am not familiar with threading etc. This code was mainly for understanding purpose. Anyway I will keep this in mind in case I go for further changes.